# How to change a hover CSS animation to a keyframe animation?

Tags: css, css-animations

```
.button_slide {
  color: #d80286;
  border-radius: 0px;
  padding: 18px 36px;
  display: inline-block;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 0 #D80286;
  -webkit-transition: ease-out 0.4s;
  -moz-transition: ease-out 0.4s;
  transition: ease-out 0.4s;
}
.slide_right:hover {
  color: #fff;
  box-shadow: inset 400px 0 0 0 #D80286;
}
#outer {
  width: 364px;
  margin: 50px auto 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}


<div class="button_slide slide_right">BUTTON: SLIDE RIGHT</div>
```

My goal is to make this animation happen when the user scrolls to it instead of when they hover over it. As I understand it, that means I need to use keyframes so that I can target with JS for the scroll, but I don't understand how to convert this into a keyframe animation and am having trouble finding the right resource to help.

Comment: CSS Tricks is a great place to start: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/keyframe-animation-syntax/

Comment: @disinfor This is much more helpful than the guide I was looking at! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

@disinfor sent a good guide. The following is working well.

CSS:

```
@keyframes BoxShadowAnimation {
  0%   {box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 0 #D80286;}
  100% {box-shadow: inset 400px 0 0 0 #D80286;}
}
@keyframes TextColorAnimation {
  0%   {color: #d80286;}
  100% {color: #fff;}
}

.Box__Outer {
  animation-name: BoxShadowAnimation;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.Box__Inner {
  animation-name: TextColorAnimation;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  font-family: "Roboto";
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

HTML:

```
  <div class="Box__Outer">
    <div class="Box__Inner">BOX SHADOW WOW!</div>
  </div>
```